# Delete empty file in tmp directory with file mask

Tags: linux, bash, debian, delete-file

Currently have this in my Debian cron:

`*/1 * * * * [ -s /tmp/#sql_362_0.MYD ] || rm -f /tmp/#sql_362_0.MYD`

I'd like to replace it so that it deletes any file matching #sql_*.MYD. I only want to delete the file if it's empty.

I assume if I did:

`*/1 * * * * [ -s /tmp/#sql_*.MYD ] || rm -f /tmp/#sql_*.MYD`

It'd delete all matching files, if just one of them is empty? That is not what I want.

Side note - this is to a band aid to an [issue](https://serverfault.com/questions/568929/mysql-tmp-file-cause-site-exception-error-crash) where MYSQL creates a temp file, that ends up taking the entire site down. After many hours couldn't find a proper fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using `find` should do the work.

```
*/1 * * * * find /tmp/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '#sql_*.MYD' -empty -delete
```

`-maxdepth 1`: do not find file in subdirectory

`-type f`: matches only regular file (no directory, no symbolic link, and so on)

`-name <pattern>`: matches the file name pattern

`-empty`: matches only empty file

`-delete`: delete that file

see `man find` for detail.